# Installer says cannot create triggers but I can with phpMyAdmin

Tags: installation

Any suggestions how to get the civicrm installer to recognize that I have permission to create triggers. The installer says I don't, but my host says I do.
I can create triggers with phpMyAdmin.
I am using MySQL - it is a new site, but I don't know the version number. 
I have asked. Will enter it when I know.

Here I am substituting the word username for my real username.
I logged into WordPress with user: username, and 
logged into phpMyAdmin with user: username 
I ran the query you suggested and got: 
Your SQL query has been executed successfully. 
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost' GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED... 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON username_site.* TO 'username'@'loc...
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON username_civi.* TO 'username'@'loc...

Comment: 1) Please confirm you're logged into phpMyAdmin as the same user as the CMS user and 2) please edit your question with the results of the following SQL: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost'`, substituting your own MySQL username (and the hostname if need be)

Comment: Oh - and also please post the database software (MySQL/MariaDB/Percona/etc.) you're using along with the version?

Comment: When you say *The installer says I don't*, it can help to share the **specific wording of the error message**. This makes it easier for helpers to know what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I found getting SUPER privileges by the host was necessary.
After that the warning about Triggers disappeared.

Comment: I'm glad that worked, but that should not be necessary unless you're running a very old version of MySQL.  The need for SUPER privilege went away with MySQL 5.5.

Comment: same worked for me even though I think I have a reasonably current mysql version (`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.21-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`). I had changed and updated some packages on my vServer which broke the triggers until I granted SUPER privilege